# Annotation using three.js

Tags: three.js

I have two cubes of .obj file.The obj file is render on the browser. I want to do is as the user click on any of the cube or anywhere on the cube one prompt box display to add annotation to that place on the cube.How to do this? I am new to three.js. Anyone can help me out?

Here is my code with.obj file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Mouse Picking</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <script src="three.js"></script>
    <script src="Detector.js"></script>
    <script src="OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script src="OBJLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="MTLLoader.js"></script>
 <script src="DragControls.js"></script>
 

    <style>
        body {
            overflow: hidden;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background: hsl(0, 0%, 10%);
        }
 </style>

</head>
<body>
 <script>
        if (!Detector.webgl) {
            Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();
        }

        var container;
  var camera, controls, scene, renderer;
        var lighting, ambient, keyLight, fillLight, backLight;
  var BlueCube, RedCube;
  var objects = [];
  
  init();
        animate();
  
  function init() {

            container = document.createElement('div');
            document.body.appendChild(container);

            /* Camera */

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
            camera.position.x = 5;
   camera.position.y = 3;
   camera.position.z = 7;

            /* Scene */

            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            lighting = true;

            ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 2.5);
            scene.add(ambient);

            keyLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(new THREE.Color('hsl(30, 100%, 75%)'), 1.0);
            keyLight.position.set(-100, 0, 100);

            fillLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(new THREE.Color('hsl(240, 100%, 75%)'), 0.75);
            fillLight.position.set(100, 0, 100);

            backLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1.0);
            backLight.position.set(100, 0, -100).normalize();
   
  
   
   /* Model */

            var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
            mtlLoader.setBaseUrl('assets/');
            mtlLoader.setPath('assets/');
            mtlLoader.load('mouse_picking.mtl', function (materials) {

            materials.preload();
   
   var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
            objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
            objLoader.setPath('assets/');
            objLoader.load('mouse_picking.obj', function (object) {
   scene.add( object );
   objects.push( object );
   });
                });
   
   raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

            /* Renderer */

          renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
              renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color("hsl(0, 0%, 10%)"));

            container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            /* Controls */

            controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
            controls.enableDamping = true;
            controls.dampingFactor = 0.25;
            controls.enableZoom = false;
   
   

            /* Events */

            window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

        }
  function onWindowResize() {

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        }

        function animate() {
   //selected();
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);

            controls.update();
   
            render();

        }

        function render() {
   renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }
  
  
    </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How should the annotation look like? Should it be an overlay like in this example (https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_pdb) or projected on the surface of your cubes (like a texture)?

Comment: The annotation should be like the example you have given. But that should be enter by the users dynamically. As the user click anywhere on the cube, one prompt box appear and they can enter some text and after enter that text, the text should appear on the place on exactly where user clicks earlier.

Comment: You may find this article helpful: https://manu.ninja/webgl-three-js-annotations/

Comment: The annotation should look like (https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/interactive-test-778258c754a74d37a72d3274b80c6ce1). @Mugen87

Comment: The annotation from sketchfab uses HTML, too. So either the `three.js` example or @DonMcCurdy's resource is the right approach. Your other requirements are not `three.js` related but typical web development stuff. It should be manageable to find some guidance for this at other places.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am already done with annotation part and for annotation I am using CSS2D Renderer three.js, but I am not getting the smoothness of the 3D model like sketchfab and I also want to add while click on the annotation, the intersected part should get camera zoom similarly sketchfab. @Mugen87

Comment: Hi @Mugen87. For annotation I am using sprite and CSS2D Renderer. But sprite texts are rotating with 3D Model with different position. How can I fix Sprite text position on 3D Model?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you subdivide the geometry of the cube mesh, and then use raycasting to determine the part of the scene (specifically, the triangle in the mesh) that was clicked. Then you could add a sprite object, which is a plane that always faces the camera, to display some text.

For more information, check out the collection of examples at http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/index.html - they are a little outdated, but the examples "Mouse Click" and "Sprite Text Labels" might help you to get started.

Comment: I tried  http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/index.html example. and its also working with .obj file. But I don't want static information added. I wanted it to add by the user.